# How would I allow a script to run ONLY IF it was accessed by another script on the SAME server

Tags: php

Recently I created a script that accesses another script to run it. The only way the second script will run, is if it is accessed from the same server. To accomplish this I've made a simple `if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX") {`

(Obviously the `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is replaced with my server's IP.)

However, I'd like the script to be more portable, so I want it to somehow detect the IP of the same server or something.

Suggestions? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` will return the IP Address of the server where the current script is executing, but yeah there's better ways to do this, such as making the script unable to be accessed from the web in the first place.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Ah I didn't remember about that one, although I knew it at some point when I made a script so I could see the various values and keys of $_SERVER. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to store the second script outside of webroot.

Comment: Not an option, but thank you, that's a very good idea that I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like...

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] ){
     // Do my stuff
} else {
     header("Location: http://elsewhere.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is tied to Apache, but you could copy the idea of stopping hot-linkers linking to your images, just change the parameters to fit your named scripts, or put those local-access only scripts in a single folder - might be a bit more manageable.

http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html